# Handle Radio on Change in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working with React and React Forms and i am having trouble trying to handle the state changes for radio buttons. I have a function `getField` which dynamically renders the type of input from the state. I have another function `HandleFormStateChange` which handles the change event for the inputs but i am running into an issue with the radio buttons. The user should be able to select only one option at a time but it seems to be selecting simultaneous options.

Please check out this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-feistel-gubif?file=/src/App.js).

This is the complete code:

```
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    Forms: [{ name: "Radio", type: "radio", options: ["a", "b", "c"] }]
  };

  handleFormStateChange = (event, idx) => {
    const target = event.target;
    const form = [...this.state.Forms];
    form[idx].value = "";
    form[idx].value = target.type === "radio" ? target.value : form[idx].value;
    this.setState({
      form
    });
  };

  getField = (field, index) => {
    switch (field.type) {
      case "radio":
        return (
          <div>
            {field.options.map(option => (
              <label key={field.type + "op" + option}>
                {option}:
                <input
                  onChange={event => {
                    this.handleFormStateChange(event, index);
                  }}
                  key={option}
                  type={field.type}
                  name={option}
                  value={option}
                />
              </label>
            ))}
          </div>
        );
      default:
        return <div>Unknown form field</div>;
    }
  };

  renderForm = () => {
    return this.state.Forms.map((field, index) => (
      <label key={index}>
        {field.name}
        {this.getField(field, index)}
      </label>
    ));
  };

  render() {
    return <div>{this.renderForm()}</div>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is selecting multiple options because your radio buttons are not grouped by their name, they have separate names of their own. I've made an edit in your [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-payne-piqs5?file=/src/App.js:847-1117) - we have to have same `name` for your radio buttons to group them together. The same is the case with checkboxes if you want to group them together.

I've made couple of changes to your code:

1. I've added a name to identify the radio-group.

   ```
   state = {
       Forms: [
         {
           name: "Radio",
           radioGroupName: "chosenAlphabet",
           type: "radio",
           options: ["a", "b", "c"]
         }
       ]
     };
   ```
2. I've changed the name attribute in your field rendering function.

   ```
   <input
      onChange={event => {
       this.handleFormStateChange(event, index);
      }}
      key={option}
      type={field.type}
      name={field.radioGroupName}
      value={option}
    />
   ```

Comment: Much thanks for the help and appreciate the tips on handling radios and checkboxes. Should be pretty handy in the future.